# Send push notification async with laravel

Tags: laravel, api, push-notification, laravel-5.5

I use laravel 5.5 as my api and after the admin activates an article from the app i send a request to the api to activate the article and send push notification to all users (iOS / Android)
Ok all that works but the problem is that the response takes a long time to return to the mobile application
My question here is what is the best way to do that ?

### update

Ok I think I'll use laravel **[queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [socket.io.](https://socket.io/) . I used this for realtime notifications. It requires nodejs.